# using TransactionInterceptor throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply reactive transaction to non-reactive return type: void

Tags: spring-integration

my code is:

```
  @Bean(R2DBC_TRANSACTION_INTERCEPTOR)
    public TransactionInterceptor R2DBCTransactionInterceptor(ReactiveTransactionManager reactiveTransactionManager) {
        return new TransactionInterceptorBuilder(true)
                .transactionManager(reactiveTransactionManager)
                .isolation(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
                .propagation(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
                .build();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "create invoice",
            adviceChain = {IntegrationConfiguration.R2DBC_TRANSACTION_INTERCEPTOR})
    public Mono<Invoice> createInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        return invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
    }
```

I got an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply reactive transaction to non-reactive return type: void
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.lambda$invokeWithinTransaction$0(TransactionAspectSupport.java:348) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]

even there is no exception during the message passing process, the createInvoice method invoked with that exception.

any demo provided for this situation?
is my configuration wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new TransactionInterceptorBuilder(true)
```

See its JavaDocs:

```
* When the {@code handleMessageAdvice} option is in use, this builder produces
* {@link TransactionHandleMessageAdvice} instance.
```

Then we go to the mentioned `TransactionHandleMessageAdvice`:

```
 * When this {@link org.aopalliance.aop.Advice}
 * is used from the {@code request-handler-advice-chain}, it is applied
 * to the {@link org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler#handleMessage}
 * (not to the
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.RequestHandler#handleRequestMessage}),
 * therefore the entire downstream process is wrapped to the transaction.
```

Now if we take a look into that `MessageHandler#handleMessage`, we'll see:

```
void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException;
```

So, that's where that transaction interceptor is injected and that's where your solution fails because of that `void` return from the `handleMessage()`.

You really need to think if you definitely need a transaction (especially reactive) for the whole sub-flow under that `@ServiceActivator`...

I mean probably just `new TransactionInterceptorBuilder()` would be OK for you to make your `@ServiceActivator` transactional and already with that reactive TX manager since you indeed return there a `Mono`.